# How to click a link that will execute but not redirect. (Mobile, Tablet)

Tags: html, jquery, button, hyperlink, tablet

According to this solution I made a button that execute the href and it is not redirect me to the page (I'am developing an web application, when someone is clicking a button a http request is running and an application is opening), the problem is when I'am testing this from my tablet, when i touch the button it redirects me to the page and I don't know how to fix this.

```js
// Act on clicks to a elements
$("#link1").on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the default action, in this case the following of a link
    e.preventDefault();
    // capture the href attribute of the a element
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    // perform a get request using ajax to the captured href value
    $.get(url, function() {
        // success
    });
});
```

```html
<a id='link1' href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want it to act like a normal link, I wouldn't use the `href` attribute but instead something more abstract like `data-href` for example. You can still get the attribute through jquery and won't have to prevent any defaults.

Comment: You should use # as href and add data-href

Comment: I wouldn't even make it a link, then you won't have to add # either. Just make it a span or button with `cursor: pointer`

Comment: I tried this but nothing is happening, I want the link to be executed so my application will open, (I have a page with 2 buttons Open - Close, when I press the Open button an http request is executed and the camera is opening, the same is happening when I press the Close button, but when I am trying this from tablet it redirect me to an 192.50.50.20 page), if you want to suggest me an other method I will appreciate it...

Answer (score 0):

This is for asynchronous and not creating new tab

You should use # as href and add data-href
// Act on clicks to a elements

```
$("#link1").on('click', function(e) {
    // prevent the default action, in this case the following of a link
    e.preventDefault();
    // capture the href attribute of the a element
    var url = $(this).attr('data-href');
    // perform a get request using ajax to the captured href value
    $.get(url, function() {
        // success
    });
});
```

and the html

```
<a id='link1' href="#" data-href="http://www.google.com">Link</a>
```

This is for creating a new tab:
change the

```
$.get(url, function() {
        // success
    });
```

to

```
window.open(url).
```

Comment: I tried this but nothing is happening, I want the link to be executed so my application will open, (I have a page with 2 buttons Open - Close, when I press the Open button an http request is executed and the camera is opening, the same is happening when I press the Close button, but when I am trying this from tablet it redirect me to an 192.50.50.20 page), if you want to suggest me an other method I will appreciate it...

Comment: what do you mean by executing application? opening new tab or just sending http request?

Comment: The camera is opening when I copy the http request and open it in a new tab, by using the jquery above the http link is executed but it is not opening as I want because I am developing an interface with buttons to open the cameras. I have fixed this with the above code for Desktop but when I touch the button from tablet it redirects me to the http link.

Comment: I try to open the camera with http request but it is not opening so yes the camera is opening only when the link is executed and is opening a new tab (but with the code above we prevent the tab opening in desktop but not in tablets)

Comment: if you need a new tab you just need to have target. change the get url to window.open()

Comment: and check if you need to stop the propagation, return false;